# How to find the length of the segment inside a circle

Tags: geometry

I have to find the length CE inside the circle but I am confused about the theorem, is it  Intersecting Chords Theorem that can help me find CE or I am wrong and there's a different way to do it?. Help please thank you!.

[image]

Comment: What are $9x^o$ and $(80-x)^o$ and 5 ?

Comment: Is the point A centre?

Comment: 5 is the length of segment FC, 9x and (80-x) are the angles

Comment: Yes A is the centre

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$CF=FE=5$ ($\perp$ line from center bisects chord)

$CE=10$

Comment: Thanks lion for the amazing answer

Comment: You are welcome